# How to remove data from a JSON result

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am using the *world time API* and want to remove the date from `JSON` : `{"currentDateTime":"2020-07-02T18:56-07:00"}`

I only want to print the hour and minutes: `18:56`

Here is what I have so far:

```
url = 'http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
result = json.loads(response.read())
time = result['currentDateTime']

#testing to get everything here.
print(time)
Output here is: 2020-07-02T18:56-07:00
```

I try to `strftime` and used the `%H:%M` format, but it gave a time that would differ by a minute or two.

How do I use the *world clock API* to print out just the time with no difference on the time zone?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would just do some string processing for such case.

```
import urllib
import requests
import json

url = 'http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
result = json.loads(response.read())
x= result['currentDateTime'][:-1].split('T')[-1]
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a substring:

```
import urllib.request
import json
url = 'http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
result = json.loads(response.read())
time = result['currentDateTime']
print(time[-6:-1])
```